# What is the name of a $n$-dimensional space where each dimension contains exactly 3 values?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, vector-spaces

Can someone tell me whether this space has a name?
Each element of the space is an $n$-dimensional point (tuple) (vector, but not sure it's a vector space?) where each element of the tuple may be either $-1$, $0$, or $1$?

It seems to me more or less the corners of a $n$-dimensional hyper cube plus all the midpoints of the edges and $(n-j)$-dimensional faces, for $j=1,\ldots,(n-1)$.

I will eventually want to talk about densities of sets of such points in the space, and also about measuring the homogeneity or clustering of a distribution of such a set of points.

Comment: It's a bit unclear from your description but it sounds like you're talking about $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)^n$

Comment: I guess you simply mean $\{-1,0,1\}^n$ as subset of $\Bbb R^n$. This doesn't have any individual name, as far as I know..

Answer (score 1):

So you have a set of $3^n$ tuples $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ with $x_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$. You can regard these as representing a set $S_n$ of $3^n$ points in $\mathbb R^n$ **or** as representing the vector space $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^n$ of dimension $n$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that these are **not** the same thing. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ the points in $S_2$ that lie on the line $\sum x_i=1$ are the two points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. But in $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^2$ the line $\sum x_i=1$ also includes a third point $(-1,-1)$.